# Can I still drink and train to run a marathon?

Tags: running, running-training-plan

I'm in my 30's, new to running and training to run my first marathon. Currently I'm at the 15-20 miles/week mark and looking forward to running my first half in November and my first marathon in December.

I still like to drink wine & occasionally drink a few bottles in a night that hasn't necessarily affected my training schedule progress so far but I fear that it may in the future.

Should I quit drinking for the rest of my training? Is it okay to have a couple glasses of wine 3-4 days/week without substantially hindering my progress or limiting my performance or is it okay as long as I'm staying hydrated and eating appropriately, sleeping well, etc.?

Comment: *Obviously* you should quit drinking, because whenever your liver has to filter alcohol, it's not going to be doing the jobs that you want it to do. That said, there is no way for us to know how well you're going to do, based on three sentences of information about you.

Comment: I wouldn't stop drinking completely (I didn't do it either). Although I only drank (very modestly)the night before a rest-day. All other nights I remained completely sober.

Answer (score 0):

Making sure you are hydrated well and keep your electrolytes up is the first step.

I wouldn't go so far as to advise to quit drinking completely. There might also be some relaxation benefits.

Do realize though that you *are* hampering your recovery. And if you do 15-20 miles/week at the moment and want to do a full marathon in december I guess you have some ramping up to do. And you need to recover well from your workouts.